# How to scroll down a docx without moving the place of the cursor

Tags: scrolling, microsoft-word-2013

Is there a way to have a shortcut key in Word (2013) that will scroll down a page while keeping the cursor at the same place in the window?

That would avoid going to the last line and scroll down.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you want the cursor to change its active line when you scroll (so the cursor is always visible), or stay in the same place in the document?

Comment: That's not what I want. I want to keep the cursor at the same place of my screen ready to type while moving the text either down either up

Answer (score 5):

You can create a macro to scroll up or down without moving the cursor, then assign a keyboard shortcut to these macros.

```
Sub ScrollUp()
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Up:=1
End Sub

Sub ScrollDown()
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=1
End Sub
```

Then assign a keyboard shortcut of your choice to these macros. (In Word 2016 go to File > Options >  Customize Ribbon > Keyboard shortcuts: Customize > Categories: Macros)

In the macro, you can change the number of scroll lines to a different number if you like.

Source: http://www.thefreewindows.com/2287/scroll-a-microsoft-word-document-without-moving-the-cursor/

Comment: I'm getting this error: “Object variable or With block variable not set.” Any ideas to solve it? I'm on Word 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to stevenkkim's solution, for Word 2016 you need:

```
Sub ScrollUp()
  ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Up:=1
End Sub
    
Sub ScrollDown()
  ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=1
End Sub
    
Sub ScrollLeft()
  ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToLeft:=1
End Sub  

Sub ScrollRight()
  ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
End Sub
```

Then assign the macros to your preferred keyboard shortcuts (I use Alt + UpArrow, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I propose a workaround if the use case is simply reading a document someone else has created and not making any edits: export/print to PDF. Navigating in a reading context is smoother in pdf reader applications.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the keyboard will work based on cursor movement like page up and page down. If you wanted to move the page with out changing the cursor place, you can use the scroll bar in the right hand side to move around the page or move center scrolling roller in mouse to move around the page.

Comment: I want to be able to move it with hotkeys. I don't use a mouse nor I usually have the scroll bar at the right of the Word window. That reduces the quantity of text available to read.